Hibernat Validator called twice
we develop an application using Jakarta EE 10 and Payara (Glassfish) 6.x.
Using @Valid in my resource methods results in my custom validators beeing called twice.
The first time everything is injected into the Validator class as expcected. I.e. @Context private UriInfo uriInfo; works like a charm.
But the second time the validator is called no injection happens. With CDI managed beans we just manually look them up using CDI.current().select(Service.class).get();.
But for UriInfo I couldn't find a similar approach.
Here are the stack trace from the first and second call to the validator. I removed the parts that are the same for both stack traces to improve readability.
isValid:82, ValidNurseCallComponentIdentifier$NurseCallComponentIdentifierValidator (at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.validation)
isValid:41, ValidNurseCallComponentIdentifier$NurseCallComponentIdentifierValidator (at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.validation)
validateSingleConstraint:180, ConstraintTree (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation)
validateConstraints:66, SimpleConstraintTree (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation)
validateConstraints:75, ConstraintTree (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation)
doValidateConstraint:130, MetaConstraint (org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core)
validateConstraint:123, MetaConstraint (org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core)
validateMetaConstraint:555, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement:518, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup:488, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup:450, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateInContext:400, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateCascadedAnnotatedObjectForCurrentGroup:629, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateCascadedConstraints:590, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateParametersInContext:880, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateParameters:283, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateParameters:235, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
onValidate:154, DefaultConfiguredValidator (org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal)
proceed:95, ValidationInterceptorExecutor (org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal)
validateResourceAndInputParams:122, DefaultConfiguredValidator (org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal)
invoke:136, AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
doDispatch:159, JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
dispatch:93, AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
invoke:478, ResourceMethodInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model)
apply:400, ResourceMethodInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model)
apply:81, ResourceMethodInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model)
run:274, ServerRuntime$1 (org.glassfish.jersey.server)
call:248, Errors$1 (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
call:244, Errors$1 (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
process:292, Errors (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
process:274, Errors (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
process:244, Errors (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
runInScope:266, RequestScope (org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal)

The second failing call:
isValid:66, ValidNurseCallComponentIdentifier$NurseCallComponentIdentifierValidator (at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.validation)
isValid$$super:-1, ValidNurseCallComponentIdentifier$NurseCallComponentIdentifierValidator$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass (at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.validation)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:77, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
proceedInternal:51, TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
proceed:78, AroundInvokeInvocationContext (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
intercept:53, WebAppExceptionInterceptor (org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.transaction.internal)
invoke:-1, GeneratedMethodAccessor416 (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
invoke:73, SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader)
proceedInternal:66, NonTerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
proceed:78, AroundInvokeInvocationContext (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
proceed:212, TransactionalInterceptorBase (org.glassfish.cdi.transaction)
transactional:115, TransactionalInterceptorRequired (org.glassfish.cdi.transaction)
invoke:-1, GeneratedMethodAccessor415 (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
invoke:73, SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader)
executeAroundInvoke:84, InterceptorMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
executeInterception:72, InterceptorMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
invoke:56, InterceptorMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
invoke:79, CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy)
invoke:68, CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy)
isValid:-1, ValidNurseCallComponentIdentifier$NurseCallComponentIdentifierValidator$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass (at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.validation)
isValid:39, ValidNurseCallComponentIdentifier$NurseCallComponentIdentifierValidator (at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.validation)
validateSingleConstraint:180, ConstraintTree (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation)
validateConstraints:66, SimpleConstraintTree (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation)
validateConstraints:75, ConstraintTree (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation)
doValidateConstraint:130, MetaConstraint (org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core)
validateConstraint:123, MetaConstraint (org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core)
validateMetaConstraint:555, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement:518, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup:488, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup:450, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateInContext:400, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateCascadedAnnotatedObjectForCurrentGroup:629, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateCascadedConstraints:590, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateParametersInContext:880, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateParameters:283, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
validateParameters:235, ValidatorImpl (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:77, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
invoke:38, AbstractBeanInstance (org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy)
invoke:106, ProxyMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy)
validateParameters:-1, Validator$ExecutableValidator$1931579803$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy (org.jboss.weld.generated.proxies.validation)
validateMethodInvocation:66, ValidationInterceptor (org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:77, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
invoke:73, SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader)
executeAroundInvoke:84, InterceptorMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
executeInterception:72, InterceptorMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
invoke:56, InterceptorMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy)
invoke:79, CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy)
invoke:68, CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler (org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy)
createWallButton:-1, WallButtonResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass (at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.rest)
invoke0:-1, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:77, NativeMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:43, DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl (jdk.internal.reflect)
invoke:568, Method (java.lang.reflect)
lambda$static$0:52, ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
invoke:-1, ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$$Lambda$1810/0x00000008016a4440 (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
run:146, AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1 (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
invoke:189, AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
doDispatch:159, JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
dispatch:93, AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal)
invoke:478, ResourceMethodInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model)
apply:400, ResourceMethodInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model)
apply:81, ResourceMethodInvoker (org.glassfish.jersey.server.model)
run:274, ServerRuntime$1 (org.glassfish.jersey.server)
call:248, Errors$1 (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
call:244, Errors$1 (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
process:292, Errors (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
process:274, Errors (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
process:244, Errors (org.glassfish.jersey.internal)
runInScope:266, RequestScope (org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal)

in the build.gradle file related entries are:
providedCompile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Final'
    providedCompile 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.1'
    providedCompile 'fish.payara.api:payara-api:6.2023.9'
    providedCompile 'fish.payara.server.core.common:container-common:6.2023.8'
    providedCompile 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:4.0.1.payara-p1'

    providedCompile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:3.1.0.payara-p1'
    providedCompile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:3.1.0.payara-p1'
    providedCompile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:3.1.0.payara-p1'

The validated resource method looks like this:
@Path("/wallbuttons")
public class WallButtonResource extends SubResource {

    [....]

    @POST
    public void createWallButton(@Valid ApiWallButton entity,
                              
                                 @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        final Long groupId = getGroupId(uriInfo);
        final UriBuilder ub = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        final Authentication authentication = AuthenticationEvaluator.getCurrentAuthentication();

        ExceptionHandlingExecutor.executeRequestWithAuthentication(executorService, () -> {
            
                final Entity created = wallButtonService.create(entity);
                asyncResponse.resume(
                    Response.created(
                        UriHelper.createURLForApiRepresentation(ub, created)).entity(created)
                        .build()
                );
            

        }, asyncResponse, AuthenticationEvaluator.getCurrentAuthentication());
    }

And the validator
package at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.validation;

import at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.ApiWallButton;
import at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.api.IdentifierExtractor;
import at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.entity.WallButton;
import at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.entity.WallButton_;
import at.ppcssolution.domain.nursecall.service.WallButtonService;
import at.seres.filter.modelfilter.AttributeFilter;
import at.seres.filter.modelfilter.ModelFilter;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraintvalidation.HibernateConstraintValidatorContext;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Constraint(validatedBy = {UniqueWallButton.UniqueIdentifierValidator.class})
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueWallButton {

    String message() default "{device.uniqueImei}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @ApplicationScoped
    class UniqueIdentifierValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueWallButton, ApiWallButton> {

        private final WallButtonService wallButtonService;
        @Context
        private UriInfo uriInfo;

        public UniqueIdentifierValidator() {
            this.wallButtonService = CDI.current().select(WallButtonService.class).get();
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(UniqueWallButton constraintAnnotation) {
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public boolean isValid(ApiWallButton value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            boolean hasMultipleIds = false;
            if(uriInfo != null) {
                final Optional<String> multipleIds = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().get("multipleIds").stream().findFirst();
                hasMultipleIds = Boolean.valueOf(multipleIds.orElse("false"));
            }
            List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<>();
            if(hasMultipleIds) {
                final Set<String> uniqueIdentifiers = IdentifierExtractor.getUniqueIdentifiers(value.getIdentifier());
                identifiers.addAll(uniqueIdentifiers);
            } else {
                identifiers.add(value.getIdentifier());
            }
            List<ModelFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
            filters.add(AttributeFilter.filter(identifiers, WallButton_.identifier));
            final List<WallButton> buttonsWithSameIdentifier = wallButtonService.getAll(filters);
            boolean isValid;

            if (buttonsWithSameIdentifier.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            } else if (buttonsWithSameIdentifier.size() == 1) {
                //If it is the same button - everything is cool
                isValid = Objects.equals(buttonsWithSameIdentifier.get(0).getId(), value.getId());
            } else {
                //more than one matching identifier -> this is definitely not valid
                isValid = false;
            }

            if (!isValid) {
                context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                if(hasMultipleIds) {
                    HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateConstraintValidatorContext =
                        context.unwrap( HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class );
                    hibernateConstraintValidatorContext.addMessageParameter("usedIdentifiers",
                            buttonsWithSameIdentifier.stream().map(wallButton -> wallButton.getIdentifier()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).toString());
                    hibernateConstraintValidatorContext
                            .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{device.uniqueIdentifiers}")
                            .addPropertyNode("identifier")
                            .addConstraintViolation();
                } else {
                    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(context.
                                    getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
                            .addPropertyNode("identifier")
                            .addConstraintViolation();
                }
            }

            return isValid;
        }



    }
}



Its @ApplicationScoped bean, created only once per application, and injected only once upon creation.

Thank you for your comment. But I can't see how this relates to my problem. The problem is, that the validator class is called twice for the same request through different stack traces

It looks like the first time it is validated by Jersey, second time by CDI. Is it possible that ApiWallButton is a CDI bean?

I also wonder why that is. ApiWallButton is a simple DTO class with only a @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) Jackson annotation and the two custom Validator annotation @UniqueWallButton @ValidNurseCallComponentIdentifier

Ok I was a little distracted but your comment got stuck in my head about ApiWallButton beeing a CDI bean. And finally I figured out the problem. In the beans.xml file the beans-discovery-mode was set to "all" instead of "annotated" causing the JAXRS resource beeing treated as CDI beans and CDI method validation kicking in. If you want to formulate that as an answer I would be happy to accept that
